# How to install windows 7 from scratch on a disk which already contains partitions

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I have following partitions on a 1 TB disk.

```
14 GB UNKNOWN recovery partition
100MB NTFS System Reserved partition for Windows 7
448GB NTFS Windows 7 system partition
468GB NTFS Data partition for windows 7
```

Now because of the problems mentioned in my other question  [here](https://superuser.com/questions/126823/1-tb-hdd-and-no-space-to-create-a-partition-for-linux)

I got a brand new windows 7 cd and want to install it from scratch after deleting all the extra partitions. But windows 7 installation doesn't give me such options. It refuses to touch the 14GB Recovery and 100 MB (reserved by previous windows 7) partition.

Any ideas ?

Note: Because of it is a dynamic disks most of the freely available tools refuse to delete the partitions on the disk.

regards.

Comment: FWIW, if you go the route of a separate partitions for Win 7 & data again, I would suggest using something small than 448GB for your Win 7 partition. I get by with around 50GB. IMO it makes it easier to keep a backup "disk image" of the Win 7 partition if it isn't humongous.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Boot CD from here: http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd
2. Format the hard drive as u wish from the tools
3. Try and install Windows 7 again

Answer (score 0):

What I do to create a clean fresh disk, is write nulls to the first track.  You can boot a live Linux CD, then use the 'dd' command to write the nulls.  Your command might look like this:

dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=8225280 count=1

You can use linux's 'fdisk -l' command to see how many bytes are in a cylinder and set the bs (block size) to that number.

I've never had trouble installing/formatting/partitioning after doing this.

Comment: Wouldn't this destroy your master boot record? It sounds like the OP wants to retain at least his data partition.

Comment: Yes, it would destroy the MBR.  This should only be done as a last resort if you are unable to use the disk at all, don't care about the data on it (or have it backed up safely), and the tools you have refuse to partition the disk.

Comment: And if he doesn't have a Linux Live CD laying around, making one is going to involve 10 extra steps that he doesn't need to do, as the Windows Setup disc already has tools to wipe the drive.

Answer (score 0):

Once Windows setup get to the Welcome Screen (right near the beginning), push Ctrl+F8. A command prompt window will popup. Enter the `diskpart` utility. Once it loads, you can `sel disk 0`, and `list part` (this will give you a list of the partitions and their numbers). From there `sel part [# from previous step]` and `del part` for each partition you want to wipe out (or you can delete them all by entering `clean` instead).